# How do I use lm to find a point on a line of best fit through a scatter graph for a given y value?

Tags: regression, linear-model, prediction, lm

I have a scatter graph I have plotted and got the summary statistics for using lm. I need to find a x value for a series of y values which were previously calculated in the code.

I was unsuccessful using predict function as the name of the calculated value is different to the name of the value plotted on the y value, and so the error "Object was not found" occurs. however how could I change the names to be the same thing as two different arrays clearly cannot have the same name.

I understand I could use the numbers in the summary and manually type them into the equation of the line however surely this manual calculation is not necessary.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did the previous calculations that you mention use a straight line "y = a * x + b" type of regression model?